# Console only printing one letter at a time, instead of full word

Tags: javascript, arrays

My goal is to have the console print randomly selected words from the `res_GREETINGS` array.

When I call the randomResponse function it is supposed to choose a random word from the `res_GREETINGS` array. Instead the console only prints one letter randomly.

Now when I substitute the `randomResponse` parameter for the name of the actual `res_GREETINGS` array, it *works fine*. When I pass in `"res" + wordBank` to randomResponse, it seems to just print out letters.

```js
let _GREETINGS = ["hello", "hi", "hey", "nice to meet you"]
let res_GREETINGS = ["yayyy", "double yayy", "triple yay"]
let userInput = "hi"

function init(wordBank) {
  for (let i = 0; i < wordBank.length; i++) {
    if (userInput.indexOf(wordBank[i]) != -1) {
      randomResponse("res" + wordBank);
    }
  }
}

function randomResponse(arr) {
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  console.log(arr[randomIndex]);
}

init(_GREETINGS);
```

Answer (score 4):

With `randomResponse("res"+wordBank);`, you're *concatenating* `res` with `wordBank` - the `wordBank` array gets implicitly converted into a string, which means that the parameter `randomResponse` gets (the `arr` variable) is a *string*, not an array. (so, `arr[randomIndex]` then refers to a *letter*, not a phrase.) Leave out "res", and it works as expected:

```js
let _GREETINGS = [
  "hello", "hi", "hey", "nice to meet you"
]
let res_GREETINGS = [
  "yayyy", "double yayy", "triple yay"
]
let userInput = "hi"

function init(wordBank) {
  for (let i = 0; i < wordBank.length; i++) {
    if (userInput.indexOf(wordBank[i]) != -1) {
      randomResponse(wordBank);
    }
  }
}

function randomResponse(arr) {
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  console.log(arr[randomIndex]);
}

init(_GREETINGS);
```

To make your code a bit more semantic and readable, you might consider using `.some` to check to see if the input exists in any of the `_GREETINGS` elements - it'll be a bit more elegant than a `for` loop:

```js
let _GREETINGS = [
  "hello", "hi", "hey", "nice to meet you"
]
let res_GREETINGS = [
  "yayyy", "double yayy", "triple yay"
]
let userInput = "hi"

function init(wordBank) {
  if (wordBank.some(phrase => userInput.includes(phrase))) {
    randomResponse(wordBank);
  }
}

function randomResponse(arr) {
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  console.log(arr[randomIndex]);
}

init(_GREETINGS);
```

Comment: @JimCiaston Just pass in `res_GREETINGS` instead of `_GREETINGS` to `init`

Answer (score 3):

Try this, you forget to pass it as array.

```js
let _GREETINGS = [
"hello","hi","hey","nice to meet you"
]
let res_GREETINGS = [
 "yayyy","double yayy","triple yay"
]
let userInput = "hi"
function init(wordBank){
        for(let i = 0; i < wordBank.length; i++){
            if(userInput.indexOf(wordBank[i]) != -1){
                randomResponse("res ", wordBank);
            }
        }
    }
    function randomResponse(res, arr){
        let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
        console.log(res + arr[randomIndex]);
    }
    
    init(_GREETINGS);
```